# Can I use ec2 to build a s3 cache server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm a beginner developer. I'm currently developing an application service with frequent image transfer. Images are sent via s3.

To reduce the cost of s3, I want to cache the image in hdd by giving a middle server such as ec2.

Is this the right way?
How do I make it in normal web service?

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to reduce your costs.

Amazon S3 charges for:

- Storage (no cheaper)
- Requests (`$0.0004 per 1,000 requests`) -- So, off-loading 1 million requests will save you 40c
- Data Transfer (no cheaper)

Also, if you are serving many images, the bandwidth of the Amazon EC2 instance, and its ability to process so many requests, is likely to be lower than what Amazon S3 can offer.

Amazon S3 can [act like a web server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html), directly providing content to the Internet. It can also serve private content by using an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object.